# How I can set auto-ISO by Sony Remote Camera API?

Tags: camera, sony

How I can set auto-ISO by Sony Remote Camera API?
I'm able to set any specific value, but what about "auto"? Since PlayMemories-Home app does it, there is a way, but it's not documented.

Thanks,
Oleg.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check/get 'available' (vs 'supported') values? Sometimes I have seen that some values are only usable if the camera is in a particular mode.

You might try changing the shooting mode and see if that then allows you to change ISO setting to auto.

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: The problem starts from there being no documentation on how to even attempt setting AutoISO in the API. For specific values you just send it the ISO number as a string; but what I'm supposed to send for auto-ISO?